# Divs reorder with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have some divs,there are until now about 90, and i want to reorder them for the mobile version,I tried flex, but it doesnt work very well, and i start doing it with the insert Before of Jquery. But i think it will be very time consuming on loading.Here is the code that i am using:

```
<script>
if($(window).width() < 1024){
$( "#img1" ).insertBefore( "#img2" );
$( "#img2" ).insertBefore( "#img3" );
$( "#img3" ).insertBefore( "#img4" );
$( "#img4" ).insertBefore( "#img5" );
$( "#img5" ).insertBefore( "#img6" );
$( "#img6" ).insertBefore( "#img7" );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample that I have tried based on the understanding. Images are added on DOM in random order. JQuery code sorts the images based on the ID and displays them in a sorted order:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgIds = [];
  $('img').each(function() {
    imgIds.push($(this).attr('id'))
  });
  imgIds.sort();

  $(imgIds).each(function(k, v) {
    if($("#" + v).length) {
      var imgClone = $("#" + v).clone();
      $(imgClone).removeAttr('id');
      $("#" + v).remove();
      $(".container_1").append($(imgClone));
    }
  });
  $(".container").remove(); // empty this container to lighten the DOM
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <img id='img1' src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=1' />
  <img id='img3' src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=3' />
  <img id='img5' src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=5' />
  <img id='img2' src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=2' />
  <img id='img4' src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=4' />
</div>
<div class='container_1'>
</div>
```

Comment: it gives me error "Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of undefined".Should i create two containers?One for the old and one for the new?

Comment: Yes. I created 2. One that has original HTML and image tags. And another empty one which will have sorted array. After sorting, the original container is removed from the DOM. So your HTML stays lighter.

Comment: I tried it, but error remains, I am using jquery 3.1.1

Comment: What's the error in your console? Please share that.

Comment: I wrote it at the first comment

Comment: Are the images added dynamically or they exists on page refresh?

Comment: They exist in page refresh.

Comment: I have updated my code. So your site already has some JS error which might be conflicting. Check the console. Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: lightbox is not defined
    at ContentSite.html:2663
(anonymous) @ ContentSite.html:2663`

Comment: I know about this error, it is also jquery version error, I was using lightbox_with_jquery and I changed the lightbox version with one that I cam implement share buttons to the lightbox

Comment: hey, i just check it, i doesnt add anything to container_1 div.

Comment: Well, above code snippet is working well. Please share the error message or console to understand why it isn't working for you.

Comment: There is no error message now, just it doesn't instantiate the divs to container_1, just remove the containet

Comment: I am uploading the code, it will be done in about 10 minutes,the gift errors are OK, there are no files yet, I made the script works under 1024 px screens.

Comment: Let me know where have you uploaded, will take a look.

Comment: The link is http://www.pcai.gr/1rstPhase_PP/ContentSite/ContentSite.html

Comment: So you need to change `$('img').each(function() {` to `$('.container .post').each(function() {`

Comment: hey, yes now it works.but it takes as items to sort the img the class post, not img id(which is #img1 etc), and completely destroys my css. I will check it, now that i have time.and be back with an update, i comes anything to your mind is helpful.

Comment: i was thinking of creating an array with 29 elements and define the id from there.

Comment: Well, you can do that. I believe, we should close this question and can take next steps offline.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var divs = $('body').find('div');
divs.sort(function (a, b) {
  return parseInt(a.id.replace('img','')) > parseInt(b.id.replace('img',''));
});
$('body').html(divs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="img3">3</div>
  <div id="img11">11</div>
  <div id="img1">1</div>
  <div id="img2">2</div>
</body>
```